# Polars read_database Treating SQL Server NULL and Empty String as the Same: How to Distinguish?

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, null, python-polars

I'm working with two SQL Server tables that have identical schemas. I'm using the read_database function from the Polars library to read these tables into DataFrames for comparison.

The issue is that one table has records with NULL values in certain columns, while the corresponding records in the other table have empty strings ('') in those columns. I need to handle these cases differently in my comparison logic.

When I read the tables using Polars' read_database, it seems to convert both NULL and empty string values to null, making it impossible to distinguish between them.

Is there a way to make Polars preserve the distinction between NULL and empty strings when reading from SQL Server?

The non-preferred workaround would be for me to use CASE statements in my SQL to change an empty column value to "::EMPTY::". Other than that, I have not found a way to modify the behavior of the read_database function itself.

Comment: are you using adbc or connectorx? If the latter, have you tried using connectorx with the same queries outside of polars to see what it does? I'm guessing this isn't polars but whatever you're using upstream. Another thing you could do is coalesce the null instead of casing the "" but that's probably more of a preference.

Comment: Hey Dean - I'm using connectorx. You raise a good point about trying the same queries with that outside of polars - I haven't done that yet. I can give that a try!